# Running method before main page loads (CherryPy)

Tags: python, jquery, webserver, cherrypy

I don't have much experience in web programming, so I'll try to simply explain the problem.

Here is my main method of a class that is run by CherryPy (cherrypy.quickstart(SLA_App())):

```
class SLA_app(Object):
    def index(self):
       global files;
       files=[...]
       createTable.createTable(files, '20/06/2012', '03/07/2012')
       cherrypy.tree.mount(SLA_App(), '/', 
        config = { '/': { 'tools.staticdir.on' :True,
       'tools.staticdir.dir' : 'some/dir',
       'tools.staticdir.index' : 'cherry.html' } 
        })
        return open('cherry.html')
    index.exposed = True
```

I created a CherryPy server.
Each time when main page loads, a method needs to be executed. That method generates HTML code in some file. It is done in createTable.createTable(files). Say, it creates insert.html . The main page that is loading has jquery method that loads the code of the file to some  and finally one gets the resulting page with everything.

Now, each time when someone enters a page I want that method to be executed. Problem is that it works only at server starting point. Every time when people enter the page, it will load the old file (method won't be invoked). How to make it work every time when page is loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. The thing is that every time web starts it should send the request to server, receive the answer and build the page dynamically. This can be accomplished with Ajax. Since I use jQuery, $.post method was quit useful in dealing.

To all that are new to this, just like me I advise to read "JavaScript and jQuery: The Missing Manual" by David Sawyer McFarland. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your call to cherrypy.tree.mount should not be done inside the index method (though I don't think that your only problem here).

```
class SLA_app(Object):
    def index(self):
       global files;
       files=[...]
       createTable.createTable(files, '20/06/2012', '03/07/2012')

       return open('cherry.html')
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.tree.mount(SLA_App(), '/', 
    config = { '/': { 'tools.staticdir.on' :True,
   'tools.staticdir.dir' : 'some/dir',
   'tools.staticdir.index' : 'cherry.html' } 
    })
```

I'm not sure what your createTable does but if it must be done once, extract it from that index method as well. Also note that when using the staticdir tool, your dir path must be absolute. Please read [this section](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/files/static.html) of the documentation.

Finally it seems your config overwrites the index method itself since both will respond to /.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, but thanks for useful advise. Did the changes.